# Drop zero values at the beginning of a time series in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, time-series

I'm using Python 3.6. I have this kind of time series with *class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'*:

```
              value
 index
2019-01-01    0
2019-02-01    0
2019-03-01    1577
2019-04-01    1715
2019-05-01    1787
2019-06-01    0
2019-07-01    1787
```

I want to delete the first two rows but no the one corresponding to June 2019.
The output will be:

```
              value
 index
2019-03-01    1577
2019-04-01    1715
2019-05-01    1787
2019-06-01    0
2019-07-01    1787
```

I can't use **iterrows()** because I have a time series pandas format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just need to remove these two rows, you can simply do `df.iloc[2:]`

For a generalized soluton, you may use `cumprod`

```
df.loc[~df.value.eq(0).cumprod().astype(bool)]
```

```
           value
2019-03-01   1577
2019-04-01   1715
2019-05-01   1787
2019-06-01      0
2019-07-01   1787
```

---

Detail:

```
>>> df.value.eq(0).cumprod()

2019-01-01    1
2019-02-01    1
2019-03-01    0
2019-04-01    0
2019-05-01    0
2019-06-01    0
2019-07-01    0
```

---

An alternative (likely nicer) solution as suggest by @user3483203

```
df.loc[df['value'].ne(0).idxmax():]
```

```
           value
2019-03-01   1577
2019-04-01   1715
2019-05-01   1787
2019-06-01      0
2019-07-01   1787
```

Comment: @La_haine are you sure you are running the pieces of code we posted? Looks like you are doing something like `df.loc[something]` where `something` is a data frame. But notice we've only passed `pd.Series` in the above answers

Comment: @La_haine `DataFrame has no attribute 'value'` means your `df` has no column named `value`. But in the example you have us, it  _does_ have a column named `value`. Just change `df.value` to `df.whatever_your_column_is_name`

Comment: If you can select the data frame with `df.value`, how come you get `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'value'.` as an error? Not sure which pandas version you have, but try to do `df['value']` instead.